# Unix : Merge the contents of two files using common key present in the files

Tags: join, awk

**Objective :** Merge the contents of two files using common key present in the files

```
 file1.txt
 =========
 key1   11
 key2   12
 key3   13


file2.txt
=========
key2   22
key3   23
key4   24
key5   25


Expected Output :
==================
key1   11
key2   12    22
key3   13    23 
key4   24
key5   25
```

**Approaches**

1. join command

   JOIN -a 1 -a 2 file1.txt file2.txt ## full outer join
2. awk (as suggested in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467690/how-to-merge-two-files-using-awk)

   awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next;}{ print $0, a[$1]}' 2.txt 1.txt

Approach 2 is resulting in right outer join and NOT full outer join

```
    key1  11
    key2  12    22
    key3  13    23
```

**Questions :**

1. What needs to be modified in approach 2 which will result in full outer join ?
2. Which would be the better approach (#1 or #2) when we have lot of key-value pairs in files (read files in GB/TB) keeping performance in view ?

Any inputs/ thoughts on the above questions is much appreciated. Many Thanks.